# Reduce the Size Of ios App

Tags: ios, json, xcode

My ios app parses data from 3 Different JSON file during runtime. I have added these files to my App bundle. One of the said JSON files is pretty huge(11 MB). My app's estimated size is 13 MB, after adding this file. Is there any way I can reduce this size? Can I somehow reduce the size of the JSON file? Is the app size directly proportional to files I have added to the bundle(seems like it obviously, but just to be sure)?

Comment: 13MB doesn't sound that big to me

Comment: Try zipping it, if it is remarkable smaller added the zip to your app and unzip before parsing. But I thing 13 MB is not too much, too.

Comment: Zipping did make it remarkably smaller..(to 2 MB)..now please tell me how can I add a zip file to bundle and unzip it?